# RStudio Terminal not displaying code and not responsive

Tags: r, terminal, rstudio

I posted this question on the RStudio Community site but haven't received any answers there and am hoping someone here will be able to help.

I am using RStudio 2022.07.2. Yesterday, it stopped displaying the project on the Terminal. The history is still there and the Console functions as normal but all I get on the Terminal is the location of the project, which is repeated every time 'enter' is pushed.

The problem seems to have started when I attempted to open a project I had not used for several months and had been created in 1.2.5042. After that, I got the same problem with all projects, including the one I had been working on, without a problem, earlier in the day.

I have tried closing the Terminal and then exiting and then restarting RStudio; and removing and reinstalling RStudio but neither of these have worked.

Terminal Diagnostics gives the following:
Global Terminal Information
Loaded TerminalSessions: 1
Handle: 'E9B67BAA' Caption: 'Terminal 1'

Terminal List Count: 2
Handle: 'E9B67BAA' Caption: 'Terminal 1' Session Created: true
Handle: '95FEE02F' Caption: 'Terminal 2' Session Created: false

Global Terminal Information
Caption: 'Terminal 1'
Title: ''
Cols x Rows '63 x 38'
Shell: 'Command Prompt'
Handle: 'E9B67BAA'
Sequence: '1'
Restarted: 'true
Exit Code: 'null'
Full screen: 'client=false/server=false'
Zombie: 'false'
Track Env 'false'
Local-echo: 'false'
Working Dir: 'Default'
Interactive: 'Always'
WebSockets: 'true'

System Information------------------
Desktop: 'true'
Remote: 'false'
Platform: 'Windows'

Connection Information
2022/10/19 10:31:35: Connect WebSocket: 'ws://127.0.0.1:7277/terminal/E9B67BAA/'
2022/10/19 10:31:35: WebSocket connected

Local-echo Match Failures

Any ideas on how to solve this would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What are you expecting it to display?  the Terminal just gives access to the system shell.   Unless you've typed something else there, it SHOULD just repeat the current directory when you hit enter.  What does it show if you type `dir`[enter]?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. What I am expecting (and was displayed until I encountered this problem) is the list of commands included in my project  so that I can work on that and run it from the Terminal.  What I am getting at present is just the location of my project e.g. C:/R project/Worlddata, where my project name is Worlddata.  When I press enter after that it simply repeats that address without loading the project.

Comment: Hi Paul. I have realised what my problem was, which came from my limited insights into RStudio. In the sudden change in display I encountered on Tuesday, I had lost the Source window, which is what I was actually looking for, not the Terminal. I have now realised my error and sorted that out. Thanks for your comment and apologies for the inconvenience.

Comment: Glad you've sorted it!